# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list - matplotlib (scatter)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting data using matplotlib. I am following this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684652/how-to-customize-marker-colors-and-shapes-in-scatter-plot) as base to plot with four labels. Below you can find the code. However, I am getting this error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "visualization_SH_Male_female.py", line 86, in <module>
    main()
  File "visualization_SH_Male_female.py", line 58, in main
    plt.scatter(x_list[indices], y_list[indices], marker=markers[i], color=colors[j])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

in this scatter plot. Can someone point how I can transform `indices` into integers?

```
import matplotlib
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing


def parse_features_from_csv(csv_file):
    feat_lst = []
    id_lst = []
    count = 0
    with open(csv_file) as fr:
        reader = csv.reader(fr, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            s_feat = row[:-1]
            identifier = row[-1]
            if count < 50:
                if (
                        identifier == 'Alan_Cumming' or identifier == 'Chiwetel_Ejiofor' or identifier == 'James_Purefoy' or identifier == 'Johnathon_Schaech' or identifier == 'Will_Poulter'):
                    identifier = 0
                else:
                    identifier = 2
            else:  # >= 50
                if (
                        identifier == 'Alan_Cumming' or identifier == 'Chiwetel_Ejiofor' or identifier == 'James_Purefoy' or identifier == 'Johnathon_Schaech' or identifier == 'Will_Poulter'):
                    identifier = 1
                else:
                    identifier = 3

            s_feat = [float(i) for i in s_feat]
            feat_lst.append(s_feat)
            id_lst.append(identifier)
            count += 1
    return feat_lst, id_lst


def main():
    face_file = 'comb.csv'

    feat_lst, labels = parse_features_from_csv(face_file)
    labels = np.array(labels)

    X_embedded = TSNE(n_components=2).fit_transform(feat_lst)

    x_list = [x for [x, y] in X_embedded]
    y_list = [y for [x, y] in X_embedded]

    # generate a list of markers and another of colors
    markers = ["o", "<"]
    colors = ['r', 'g']

    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(2):
            lab = i + j
            indices = list(map(int, labels == lab))
            print(indices)
            plt.scatter(x_list[indices], y_list[indices], marker=markers[i], color=colors[j])
    plt.legend(['0', '1', '2', '3'])
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: "However, I am getting this error, TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list in this scatter plot." You should show the full, formatted error traceback. Note that it will give you line numbers showing where in the code the problem occurred.

Comment: I made necessary changes in the question. @KarlKnechtel

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what's wrong with your code. `indices` is a list which cannot serve as an index for another list. Try `slices` instead or create a subset list for your plotting task.

Comment: Okay, so as it says: `indices` is a list that you produced with the previous line `indices = list(map(int, labels == lab))`. `x_list` and `y_list` are native Python lists, not Numpy arrays; they cannot be indexed this way. I don't understand what you were hoping would be the result. My best guess is that you should be using some kind of Numpy-based transformation on `X_embedded` in the first place instead of the list comprehensions....

Comment: Yeah, I understand the error, I am trying to find all indices from the list to plot. @offeltoffel

Answer (score 1):

In python, this won't work:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [2,3]
c = a[b]
```

because your index (`[]`) needs to be an integer or slice, not a list.

Simplest method would be to create a sub-list, only containing the items you need by list comprehension. In your case, this is one way to do that:

```
indices = list(map(int, labels == lab))

x_sublist = [x_list[i] for i in range(len(x_list)) if i in indices]
y_sublist = [y_list[i] for i in range(len(y_list)) if i in indices]

plt.scatter(x_sublist, y_sublist, marker=markers[i], color=colors[j])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you use python lists instead of numpy arrays. Since the code isn't runnable, the following is a minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([.4,.8,1.2,1.6,2.0,2.4])
y = np.array([.1,.2,.3,.7,.6,.5])

lab = np.array([1,1,2,2,1,2])

for l in np.unique(lab):
    indices = (lab == l)
    plt.scatter(x[indices],y[indices], label=str(l))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]